# Comparing between two String list does not go right

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I'm trying to swap elements in a string list. The number of possibilities depends on the length of the list. The swapping is stopped when the list returns to its original form. I make a copy of this list, and at the end of a while loop, I make my condition. the problem is it doesn't print all the possibilities, and when I put the list in its raw form in the condition, it works perfectly. My question is why the latter form doesn't work?
It has to work because this code is a part of a bigger one.

```py
def swaps():
    alpha = ["aba","bbb", "bab"]
    beta = alpha 
    print(f"this is beta {beta}")
    print(alpha)
    while True:
        for a in range(0,len(alpha-1)):
            alpha[a],alpha[a+1]=alpha[a+1],alpha[a]
            print(alpha)
       # This form works: if alpha == ["aba","bbb","bab"]
        if alpha = beta:
            break
```

Comment: I posted that wrong, but it is == in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong, you assign reference to same list (not a copy) to value beta:

```
 alpha = ["aba","bbb", "bab"]
    beta = alpha
```

Just change to

```
 alpha = ["aba","bbb", "bab"]
    beta = list(alpha)
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` is the assignment operator. You probably meant to use, `==`, which is the equality check operator:

```
if alpha == beta:
    break
```